# How can I create a background Python environment/daemon with modules pre-loaded that I can make system calls to?

Tags: python, shell, asynchronous, command-line, daemon

I'm creating a program which makes use of a Python library in another language. As an interface, it uses a library to make an asynchronous system call to a series of Python commands; when the call finishes and returns the desired text, it writes to the UI. Right now, the asynchronocity is working -- though the system call takes a while, it doesn't block the UI and allows the user to continue to interact while the call runs for ~10 seconds. However, from experimentation I noticed that most of the delay in the script comes from a single command: a module import. I am importing just a single command, but it has a lot of dependencies, it appears.

So, what I'd like to do, is have a background process, started via a system call, that creates a Python REPL-like environment which loads the module and waits to receive commands. When it receives a command (via a system call), it evaluates it in the environment and then returns the output, avoiding the issue where the module is wastefully loaded and unloaded.

Is this possible?

I've been researching daemons and am wondering if there are any tools specifically designed for such tasks -- in particular receiving input from system calls.

A note: I'm not worried about calls to the environment being asynchronous; I handle that in the program itself anyways.

Lastly, I apologize in case I'm not using the right terminology to describe what I'm looking for; I'm happy to elaborate but new to asynchronous programming.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.